# C++ / SFML: Printing convex shapes to the screen using two recursive calls only displays the shapes from the first recursive call and not the second

Tags: c++, recursion, sfml, fractals, convex

I am using SFML and coding in C++.  The program I am writing must be a recursive implementation.

My goal is to create a function that recursively draws a square to the screen in different positions and rotations dependent upon the previously drawn square.

Each subsequent square should be smaller than the previous function call and rotated 45 degrees to the left( from the left corner of the previous square ) or 45 to the right of the previous square.

Each new square spawns two more squares etc..

My idea is to pass the upper left point and the upper right point of a square to two different recursive function calls and use these points as starting points for the subsequent squares.

While the squares generated will also pass upper left and right corners to recursive function calls etc..

The code I have developed is not displaying both squares that should have been generated from the recursive function calls.  Only one side is being shown.

I have developed the following code (Please forgive my code.. I haven't been coding in C++ for too long..)

DRIVER of PROGRAM ( main.cpp )

```
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include "PTree.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace sf;

int main( int argc, char* argv[ ] )
{
  double L = 0.0; // Length of square sides
  int N = 0; // Number of times to call recursive function           

  L = atol( argv[ 1 ] );
  N = atoi( argv[ 2 ] );
  Vector2f vPoint;
  vPoint.x = 0;
  vPoint.y = 0;

  // Create and Display Window
  PTree tree( L, N );
  return 0;
}
```

---

( PTree.hpp )

```
#ifndef PTREE_H
#define PTREE_H

using namespace std;
using namespace sf;

class PTree /*:public sf::Drawable, public sf::Transformable*/{
public:
  // Constructor
  PTree( double L, int N );
  // Destructor
  ~PTree();

  // Recursive function to draw Pythagorias Tree
  void pTree( double L, int N, Vector2f vPoint, Vector2f vOrigin, float rotation );

private:
  float width = 0;
  float height = 0;
  int originX = 0;
  int originY = 0;
  float rotation = 0;
  RenderWindow window;
  int angle1 = 0;
  int angle2 = 0;

};

#endif // PTREE_H included
```

---

( PTree.cpp )

```
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <math.h>
#include "PTree.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace sf;

// Constructor
PTree::PTree( double L, int N )
{ 
  width = ( 6 * L );
  height = ( 4 * L );
  Vector2f vPoint = { width/2, height - 1 };
  Vector2f vOrigin;
  vOrigin.x = L/2;
  vOrigin.y = L;
  /* vPoint.x = width/2;
  vPoint.y = height - 1;
 */
  window.create( VideoMode( width, height ), "Pythagoras Fractal Tree" );
  pTree( L, N, vPoint, vOrigin, 0 );
}

// Destructor
PTree::~PTree(){}
/*###########################################################################*/

// Recursive function to draw Pythagorias Tree
void PTree::pTree( double L, int N, Vector2f vPoint, Vector2f vOrigin, float rotation  )
{
  Vector2f vPointR;

  if( N < 1 )
  {
    return;
  }

  // Define a convex shape called convexSquare
  ConvexShape convexSquare( 4 );
  convexSquare.setPoint( 0, Vector2f( 0, 0 ));
  convexSquare.setPoint( 1, Vector2f( 0, L ));
  convexSquare.setPoint( 2, Vector2f( L, L ));
  convexSquare.setPoint( 3, Vector2f( L, 0 ));

  convexSquare.setOutlineThickness( 1.f );
  convexSquare.setFillColor( Color::Black );
  convexSquare.setOutlineColor( Color::White );

  convexSquare.setPosition( vPoint );
  convexSquare.setOrigin( vOrigin );
  convexSquare.setRotation( rotation );

  while( window.isOpen( ))
  {
    Event event;
    while( window.pollEvent( event ))
    {
      if( event.type == Event::Closed )
      {
        window.close( );
      }
    }
    if( N >= 0 )
    {
    window.draw( convexSquare );
    window.display( );
    L = ( L * ( sqrt(2)/2 ));
    N = N - 1;
    rotation = rotation - 135;
    cout << "LOOPS:" << N << endl;

//left
    vPoint = convexSquare.getTransform( ).transformPoint(   convexSquare.getPoint( 0 ));
    vOrigin = convexSquare.getPoint( (angle1) );
    pTree( L, N, vPoint, vOrigin, rotation );
    angle1 = (( angle1 + 1 ) % 4 );

//right
    vPointR = convexSquare.getTransform( ).transformPoint( convexSquare.getPoint( 3 ));
    vOrigin = convexSquare.getPoint( 2 );
    pTree( L, N, vPointR, vOrigin, rotation-90 ); 

    }
  }
cout << "X value =" << vPoint.x << "     Y value = " << vPoint.y << endl;
```

So far I have tried to return various points of the convex shapes for the second recursive call to the function pTree.  This did not display anything either.

Initially I was only using Vector2f vPoint and modifying it prior to each recursive call but after exhausting my knowledge base for a solution I created a new variable specifically for the right side squares called Vector2f vPointR.

The SFML documentation does not provide sufficient examples for noobs like myself. The API is essentially a list of options with minimal examples if any for each function. Ive searched the internet to the best of my ability to see if I am passing the wrong points but could not find an answer.

The one thing that did work ( although not entirely correct ) was when I switched the recursive calls... meaning I moved the call for the right side squares before the call for the left side squares but the problem with this is that the left side s
quares were not displaying.

At this point I am also trying to work out the proper rotation for each square but this is the least of my problems.

Is there an issue with the way I am trying to display these squares recursively?

I am not sure where to go from here other than Stack Overflow for help.

Thanks for your time and expertise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't recursively call the entire `while` loop. Only recurively call the drawing part

```
// Initialize window...

while (window.isOpen())
{
    sf::Event event;
    // Handle events...

    window.clear();

    // call the recursive function here

    window.display();
}
```

Also you may want to use `sf::RectangleShape` to draw instead of `sf::ConvexShape`

Here's a working "example":

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <cmath>

void drawPythagoreanTree(sf::RenderTarget&, const float, const int);

int main()
{
    const float L = 150;
    const int N = 14;

    const unsigned width = static_cast<unsigned>(6 * L);
    const unsigned height = static_cast<unsigned>(4 * L);
    sf::RenderWindow window{{width, height}, "Pythagorean Tree"};
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        for (sf::Event event; window.pollEvent(event);)
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }
        window.clear(sf::Color::White);
        drawPythagoreanTree(window, L, N);
        window.display();
    }
}

void drawPythagoreanTree(sf::RenderTarget& target, const int N,
                         const sf::RectangleShape& parent)
{
    static const float halfSqrt2 = sqrt(2.f) / 2;

    if (N < 1) return;
    target.draw(parent);
    auto const& sz = parent.getSize();
    auto const& tf = parent.getTransform();

    auto childL = parent;                    // copy parent's color and rotation
    childL.setSize(sz * halfSqrt2);          // resize
    childL.setOrigin(0, childL.getSize().y); // bottom left corner
    childL.setPosition(tf.transformPoint({0, 0})); // reposition
    childL.rotate(-45);
    drawPythagoreanTree(target, N - 1, childL);

    auto childR = parent;               // copy parent's color and rotation
    childR.setSize(sz * halfSqrt2);     // resize
    childR.setOrigin(childR.getSize()); // bottom right corner
    childR.setPosition(tf.transformPoint({sz.x, 0})); // reposition
    childR.rotate(45);
    drawPythagoreanTree(target, N - 1, childR);
}

void drawPythagoreanTree(sf::RenderTarget& target, const float L, const int N)
{
    sf::RectangleShape rect{{L, L}};
    // set origin to center of the rect, easier to center position on screen
    rect.setOrigin(rect.getSize() / 2.f);
    rect.setPosition(target.getSize().x / 2.f, target.getSize().y - L / 2.f);
    rect.setFillColor(sf::Color::Black);
    drawPythagoreanTree(target, N, rect);
}
```

Comment: Wow! You are awesome.  Initially I had used RectangleShape but I was having issues using the "getPoint" function.  After wasting a day on that I gave up and switched to a convexShape so that I would know for sure what points I was accessing.  I totally admire your skills.  Dyno-Mite!!

Comment: Now, I am just going to spend the next 4 hours or so studying your code in detail and am going to switch back to RectangleShape. Thank you for your help.  Take care.